# ctypes non-valid Win32 dll with valid win32 dll

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to wrap a small cpp file that gets the Jumbo icon for a file. However, when I try to call it from the command line started in the directory of the dll and use the following to call the dll, it doesn't work.

## command line (in same dir as dll)

```
from ctypes import *
lib=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("GetIcon.dll")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    
> File "", line 1, in 
>           
> File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
>              
> return self._dlltype(name)
>           
> File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 365, in **init**
>              
> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>           
> WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

## GetIcon.cpp

```
// GetIcon.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlguid.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <commoncontrols.h>

HICON GetJumboIcon(char *filePath);



HICON GetJumboIcon(LPCWSTR filePath) {
    SHFILEINFOW sfi = { 0 };
    SHGetFileInfo(filePath, -1, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
    //Get Image list for system
    HIMAGELIST* imageList;
    HRESULT hResult = SHGetImageList(SHIL_EXTRALARGE, IID_IImageList, (void**)&imageList);
    if (hResult == S_OK) {
        HICON hIcon;
        hResult = ((IImageList*)imageList)->GetIcon(sfi.iIcon, ILD_TRANSPARENT, &hIcon);

        if (hResult == S_OK) {
            //if it works, return it.
            return hIcon;
        }

    }
}
```

I am using x64 Python and I amm using VStudio 2013

Comment: Probably your project targets 32-bit x86 instead of x64. Just rebuild the DLL using the correct CPU target. And make sure you're exporting symbols, either using `__declspec(dllexport)` in the declarations or with a module .DEF file.

Comment: That is what I was suspecting, but I am using VS 2013 Pro, but I don't seem to have any other options beyond win32.

Comment: Are you setting the target in the configuration manager? See [How to: Configure Projects to Target Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun, I didn't see x64, so I created a new one with win32 as a base. I recompiled, and it still didn't work. (So I am guessing I need to change some values somewhere).

Comment: I tried changing the config according to [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx) (see `To copy Win32 project settings into a 64-bit project configuration`) but that didn't work either. Some of the configuration options didn't appear.